# How do one count rows in powerquery table that contain just text values

Tags: excel, powerquery

Good day all,how can one count rows in a table in powerquery containing just text values.

I want my table in this format.

| Mail | listern | Boby | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | 1 | C | 2 |
| B | 0 | 3 | 1 |

Comment: You can do it by formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
 let
        Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WclJQ0lEyBBHOCkqxOlABAxBhDBSIBQA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Mail " = _t, #"listern " = _t, #"Boby " = _t]),
        #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each 
        let a = Record.ToList(_),
        b = List.Transform(a, each try Number.From(_) otherwise "Text" ),
        c = List.Select(b, each _ = "Text" ),
        d = List.Count(c)
        in d,  Int64.Type)
    in
        #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: what if i have more than 3 columns, how do i handled this dynamically?

Comment: This should already be dynamic. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yeah, have tried it, however, when i add another field name to the table, it throws an error, you have supplied 3 keys and now using 4 values, what is? Thank you

Comment: The code works for any number of columns. I suggest posting a new question with all your code, data and error message.

Comment: Thank you @David, This no one faults. It is powerquery engine and version. If you are using 2016 excel version, and the powerquery version am using, there is a slight variation. For instance,For your data to be recognize as a table you , must convert to it to a list, then  using the tools above convert to table. You can now use any of your previous steps, after you have followed what have outlined.. Same goes with, adding index number to your table. If you are using 2016 excel version, there is a compatibility issues, you got remove the last argument or parameter, the (INT type value)

Comment: Glad you sorted it

Answer (score 1):

Another way in PowerQuery

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn("#PriorStepNameHere", "TOTAL", each  List.Sum(List.Transform(Record.ToList(_), each try Number.From(_)-Number.From(_) otherwise 1)))
```

Comment: This would have been short n simplest approach.However,i ran the query ,but saying  cant convert my  "previous steps Name" to type table.....

Comment: Did you actually put your previous step name there or did you literally use **#"PriorStepNameHere"**?  You need to use your real prior step table name in place of that placeholder. Maybe it's **Source**?

Comment: i use my previous steps name and not  #"PriorStepNameHere"..it is saying cant covert that my previous steps name to table...May be this could be powerquery version issues or excel version.I am using 2016 excel version.

Comment: Unless you edit your question to put in your current code, I don't know what your previous step name actually has -- text, a list, a table, etc

Comment: Thank you,horseyride it was as result of mix data types

Answer (score 0):

If you wish you can do it by formula.

```
=SUM(--ISTEXT(A2:C2))
```

[image]